# Showing only outer Fishnet boundaries

Tags: arcgis-pro, vector-grid, boundaries

I have a fishnet layer where some empty cells are nested within. I'd like to only show the boundary of the filled cells (color set no fill, but no inner cell boundaries of adjacent cells). How can I best delete the boundaries between adjacent cells?

I'm using ArcGIS Pro

[image]

Comment: @BERA, sounds like an answer

Comment: Look at the Union Tool to fill in the inner gaps, there is a NO_GAPS option. I would run Union before Dissolve.

Answer (score 6):

I dont think there is a way of only symbolizing the outer borders. But you can use [Dissolve tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/dissolve.htm) to create a new feature class which will not have the inner borders. Then select no fill/transparent fill and symbolize only the borders.

[image]

(You probably dont need to use any dissolve attribute)